# Find Everything between 2 strings -- Sed

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep

I have file which has data in below format.

```
{"default":true,"groupADG":["ABC","XYZ:mno"],"groupAPR":true}
{"default":true,"groupADG":["PQR"],"groupAPR":true}
```

I am trying to get output as

```
"ABC","XYZ:mno"
"PQR"
```

I tried doing it using sed but somewhere I am going wrong .

```
 sed -e 's/groupADG":[\(.*\)],"groupAPR"/\1/    file.txt
```

Regards.

Note: If anyone is rating the question negative, I would request to give a reason also for same. As I have tried to fix it myself , since I was unable to do it I posted it here. I also gave my trial example.

Comment: If you just want the stuff in square brackets, maybe `sed -n 's/.*\([[].*[]]\).*/\1/p' file.txt` ?

Comment: Great .. Thank you so much .. Can you post it as answer so that I can accept it .

Comment: No problem - happy to help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is one potential solution:

```
sed -n 's/.*\([[].*[]]\).*/\1/p' file.txt
```

To exclude the brackets:

```
sed -n 's/.*\([[]\)\(.*\)\([]]\).*/\2/p'
```

Also, this would work using AWK:

```
awk -F'[][]' '{print $2}' file.txt
```

Just watch out for edge cases (e.g. if there are multiple fields with square brackets in the same line you may need a different strategy)

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples, following may also help you on same.

```
awk 'match($0,/\[[^]]*/){print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)}' Input_file
```

OR with OP's attempts try with `/"groupADG"` also:

```
awk 'match($0,/"groupADG":\[[^]]*/){print substr($0,RSTART+12,RLENGTH-12)}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

With `awk` setting `FS` as `[][]` and the condition `/groupADG/`

```
awk -F'[][]' '/groupADG/ {print $2}' file
"ABC","XYZ:mno"
"PQR"
```